# Playing video from custom live stream (Android)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, rtmp

My android app needs to play a live video from a remote RTMP server (Adobe Flash Media Server).

As android's `android.media.MediaPlayer` doesn't support rtmp protocol, I found a library which provides me with streaming functionality. I.e. I can connect and receive portions of video stream as byte array.

The question is how I can use this incoming video stream data to display it in a view?

It seems that current standard API doesn't allow me to do that. `MediaPlayer` accepts either file or url. For audio data there is an `AudioTrack` which allows to achieve similar goal to mine, but for audio. For video I don't see an option.

Any suggestions are appreciated, maybe there is a third party media library which may provide the functionality for Android.

Comment: try Vitamio library it can handle very much different formats and streams

Comment: thank you for the comment. it is a very good library. I tried it. however I still wasn't able to run my live rtmp stream, while on stream based on file it works like a clock. So still looking for solutions.

Comment: Hello can you send me the rtmp link so i can try it.